# GPG signing Git commits after updating MacOSX hangs on password entry

Tags: git, macos, gnupg

I think this started happening after I updated the lastest OSX version, which might or might not have contained a new version of Git. But now, almost every time I try to sign my commits (either through `git commit -S` or `git rebase -S`):

1. I get the password prompt
2. Enter the password
3. Press enter and nothing happens. No 'Permission Denied: Invalid Password', nothing.
4. I have to Ctrl-C to get out of the prompt.

Not sure if this is a known issue on Git or El Capitan 10.11.6, but its getting vexing since I always sign my git commits.

I've also checked that no other GPG processes are running and nothing.

Comment: Try adding two lines reading `verbose` to your `gpg.conf` to get some more details what's happing. This sounds like an issue with `gpg-agent`, but additional information will be required for debugging.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was an issue with the agent as well, but the agent doesn't actually run in the background when signing a commit, it's just the gpg command. In any case I just restarted my computer and it started working again. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 6):

EDIT :

I was also stuck like you at "*You need a passphrase to unlock secret key for*" and nothing was happening when using GPG with git.

**The solution is :**

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

It solves the problem and it'll now ask you for the password, with a beautiful prompt.

**Don't forget** to add it to your .bashrc (or .profile / .bash_profile) :

```
echo "export GPG_TTY=$(tty)" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Hope it will help you :)